# Limiting SED to the first 10 characters of a line

Tags: bash, sed

I'm running sed as a part of a shell script to clean up bind logs for insertion into a database.

One of the sed commands is the following:

```
sed -i 's/-/:/g' $DPath/named.query.log
```

This turns out to be problematic as it disrupts any resource requests that also include a dash (I'm using : as a delimiter for an awk statement further down).

My question is how do I limit the sed command above to only the first ten characters of the line?  I haven't seen a specific switch that does this, and I'm nowhere near good enough with RegEx to even start on developing one that works.  I can't just use regex to match the preceding numbers because it's possible that the pattern could be part of a resource request.  Heck, I can't even use pattern matching for ####-##-## because, again, it could be part of the resource.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [almost always] simpler with awk:

```
awk '{target=substr($0,1,10); gsub(/-/,":",target); print target substr($0,11)}' file
```

Comment: Sir, I think that'll do it.  Thank you VERY much!

Comment: Or even (untested) `perl -pe 'substr($_, 0, 10) =~ s/:/-/g' file`

Comment: @tripleee: Your (untested) comment doesn't work for me (but I don't know perl).

Comment: Works for me, although I guess I swapped the order of `:` and `-` in the substitution.  So this one replaced colons with dashes, not vice versa ... Sorry about that (-:  By the by, if it's just a single character, you could use `y/-/:/` instead of `s/-/:/g`, but the difference is going to be quite marginal.

Answer (score 2):

I think the shortest solution, and perhaps the simplest, is provided by sed itself, rather than awk[ward]:

```
 sed "h;s/-/:/g;G;s/\(..........\).*\n........../\1/"
```

Explanation:

- (h) copy everything to the hold space
- (s) do the substitution (to the entire pattern space)
- (G) append the hold space, with a `\n` separator
- (s) delete the characters up to the tenth after the `\n`, but keep the first ten.

Some test code:

```
 echo "--------------------------------" > foo
 sed -i "h;s/-/:/g;G;s/\(..........\).*\n........../\1/" foo
 cat foo
 ::::::::::----------------------
```

Comment: Good! Perhaps a slight improvement `sed 'h;y/-/:/;G;s/^\(.\{10\}\).*\n.\{10\}/\1/'`

Comment: @potong: Yes, you are correct. *But* some older systems don't support this syntax. *And* it is less clear.

Comment: @potong: But your solution is *shorter* than mine, by seven characters (ignoring the unnecessary ^). The `y` saved one character.

Comment: Brevity is not a desirable quality of software, conciseness is, and given you HAVE to explain it the sed solution is no longer even brief. The sed solution would also have to be completely re-written with some other cryptic combination of letters and punctuation marks given the slightest change in requirements. For example, let's say I wanted to add the number of "-"s replaced with ":"s to the start of each line. In awk you'd put `c=` before the gsub() and `c` after the print. In sed? sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk.

Comment: nice one. It can be shortened further (though less efficient): `sed 's/........../&\n/;h;y/-/:/;G;s/\n.*\n//'`

.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how make sed do it per se, however, I do know that you can feed sed the first 10 characters then paste the rest back in, like so:

`paste -d"\0" <(cut -c1-10 $DPath/named.query.log | sed 's/\-/:/g') <(cut -c11- $DPath/named.query.log)`

Comment: This spits the output onto the screen rather than into the file, but this could work as well.  Thanks for the post.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
cut -c 1-10 $DPath/named.query.log | sed -i 's/-/:/g'
```

The cut statemnt takes only the first 10 chars of each line in that file. The output of that should be piped in a file. As of now it will just output to your terminal

Comment: i THINK the OP wanted to modify "-"s in just the first 10 characters of a longer line, not truncate the line to 10 characters and then modify all "-"s. Also, I wonder what sed's "-i" will do with no file to modify....